# Children's book about a child who captures tadpoles with his uncle

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for the name/author of a children's book, I read it in the early 1990s.

The book was about a child whose uncle comes to stay with him. They go to a creek to capture tadpoles with some of the child's friends (or possibly family). The other children capture a lot of tadpoles in their jars, but the uncle tells the child to only capture a small number. The other children laugh at the main child for such a small number of tadpoles. The uncle also makes the child put leaves in the jar for the tadpoles to eat and holes in the lid for air.

The uncle leaves and a few weeks later the child compares the success of their tadpoles to the other children. All of the child's tadpoles have become big frogs. The other children each only had one or two tadpoles that grew to frogs and they were all much smaller.